# Graphics and Sound!

Tags: sound, graphics

How do you change the graphical settings such as the 3D effects on the display for windows etc. Also my laptop has 4 speakers but it seems only 2 are being used... is there any way to fix this?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

For the 3D effects, you can try `Compiz Config Settings Manager`.
**NOTE:** You can break your computer when using CCSM.

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

For extra effects, install `compiz-plugins-extra`

Comment: Im talking about the when you use to be able to change the graphical effects of the windows and little things like that.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'graphical effects of the windows and little things like that'? What are you trying to achieve and what have you tried so far? Please edit your question to include this info. And be specific and clear please.